# Symfony2: SecurityExtension::addUserProviderFactory() and PropelBundle

Tags: symfony, propel

I am currently migrating a Symfony2 website and I got an issue I am not able to fix.

The error message I got is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension::addUserProviderFactory()
>   in [...]vendor/bundles/Propel/PropelBundle/PropelBundle.php on line 73

Here is my deps file:

```
[symfony]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=origin/2.0

[twig]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
    version=v1.8.2

[monolog]
    git=http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog.git
    version=1.0.2

[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.1.4

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.5

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.6

[swiftmailer]
    git=http://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git
    version=v4.2.0

[assetic]
    git=http://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git
    version=v1.0.3

[twig-extensions]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions.git

[metadata]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata.git
    version=1.0.0

[SensioFrameworkExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[JMSSecurityExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
    version=origin/1.0.x

[SensioDistributionBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[SensioGeneratorBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[AsseticBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[Phing]
    git=https://github.com/phingofficial/phing.git

[Propel]
    git=https://github.com/propelorm/Propel.git

[PropelBundle]
    git=https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Propel/PropelBundle
    branch=origin/1.0

[PdfBundle]
    git=git://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Ps/PdfBundle

[PHPPdf]
    git=git://github.com/psliwa/PHPPdf.git
    version=origin/1.1.x
```

To sum up, I am using Symfony 2.0 (I can not use 2.1: remote server is in PHP 5.3.2 and it is impossible to migrate to PHP 5.3.3 because of Plesk) and related Propel version (1.0).

Here is also my AppKernel:

```
$bundles = array(
    new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
    new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
    new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
    new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
    // My application bundles
    new Ps\PdfBundle\PsPdfBundle(),
    new Propel\PropelBundle\PropelBundle(),
);
```

And my autoload.php file, if it can help:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony'          => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    'Sensio'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'JMS'              => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Doctrine\\Common' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-common/lib',
    'Doctrine\\DBAL'   => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib',
    'Doctrine'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/lib',
    'Monolog'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/monolog/src',
    'Assetic'          => __DIR__.'/../vendor/assetic/src',
    'Metadata'         => __DIR__.'/../vendor/metadata/src',
    'Ps' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'PHPPdf' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib',
    'Imagine' => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib', __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib/vendor/Imagine/lib'),
    'Zend' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib/vendor/Zend/library',//If you have used ZF2 packages already, you should skip this entry
    'ZendPdf' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/PHPPdf/lib/vendor/ZendPdf/library',
    'Propel' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',
    'Phing'  => __DIR__.'/../vendor/phing/classes/phing',
));
```

Have you any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be loading the wrong version of the PropelBundle.

In your deps file, instead of writing `branch=origin/1.0` for the PropelBundle, write `version=origin/1.0`:

```
[PropelBundle]
    git=https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Propel/PropelBundle
    version=origin/1.0
```

Comment: Indeed, there was a mistake in my deps file. I wrote _branch_ instead of _version_. I hate this kind of error. Really simple to fix, but really hard to locate. All is working now! Thanks. :)